# Desktop (content) editing software for ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

I know there are two apps on EE official page, Marsedit and Ecto, but both seems outdated, can someone confirm me that they are working ok with EE2 for publishing etc, or there is another app doing the same job?

I found this article http://eeinsider.com/blog/using-marsedit-3-with-expressionengine-2/ but the tutorial is gone I guess :(

Thank you

Comment: MarsEdit has a trial, have you given that a go? For what it's worth Archive.org has [a cache](http://web.archive.org/web/20110718162642/http://www.antidotecreative.com/blog/configuring_marsedit_3_expressionengine_2/) for that tutorial, but basically you should be fine so long as you enable the metaweblog API and setup configs for each of your channels. I don't think any of these APIs have changed for a long time, so the core functionality should certainly work.

Comment: MarsEdit works with EE2. You can use this information from the EE user guide as a reference http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/metaweblog_api/index.html#marsedit

Comment: Yeah, I never used metaweblog api, but I will try marsedit and I saw that someone is using MS Live Writer for Win, any experience with it?